# How to get a height:100% div in a height:auto div?

Tags: html, css

Here is my HTML :

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="red"></div>
    <div id="yellow">
        <div id="green"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS :

```
#container { height:auto; width:100%; background:orange; float:left; }
#red       { height:100%; width:200px; background:red; float:left; position:relative; }
#yellow    { height:100%; width:calc(100% - 210px); background:yellow; float:right; position:relative; padding:5px; }
#green     { height:300px; width:100%; background:green; }
```

Here is a sample : https://jsfiddle.net/cc5xL660/

As it is in the jsfiddle, the `#red` `div` is invisible. I'm looking for a way to make the `#red` `div` visible without a specific `height` dimension. Of course, I could give a `height:300px` to the `#red` `div` but the `#green` div is supposed to be dynamic. I would like the `#red` div to have the same height.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to utilize specifically HTML/CSS for this solution. The % property forces the child element to meet the parents height, but the height has to be predefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to give

- `position: relative` to #container
- `position: absolute` to #red

Your JSFiddle edited: https://jsfiddle.net/cc5xL660/4/

Comment: Thank you very much ! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display:flex` to do that. Have a look at **[here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)**

```css
#container {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background: orange;
  float: left;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  align-items:stretch;
}

#red {
  /*height: 100%;*/
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

#yellow {
  /*height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% - 210px);*/
  background: yellow;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
  flex:1 0;
}

#green {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div id="red"></div>

  <div id="yellow">

    <div id="green"></div>

  </div>

</div>
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cc5xL660/5/)**

Comment: Your solution works very well, but it's quite more complicated than the other one. Anyway, I voted up for your answer, thank you.

Comment: Try to understand flex. It's the future.

Comment: Yes. It is complicated for new CSS learners and the answer you chose is obviously is the best, easier and cross browser compatible. But `flex` is much more easier to implement and needs very less effort to create more complex designs once you get to know it and it is becoming more and more browser compatible everyday. So I suggest you to have a look at it if you are interested.